# Where did the linear approximation/linearization formula come from?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, approximation, linear-approximation

Where did the linear approximation/linearization formula come from?  I understand that it takes root in the point-slope form and slope intercept form of a linear equation, but I don't understand where they got the exact formula $$f(x) \approx f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$$  Also, where did Newton's Method come from?  Can someone please explain this, or rather the individual components of the equation, to me?

Thanks!

Comment: This follows from Taylor series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the two points $(x_0, f(x_0))$ and $(x,f(x))$. Now suppose we wanted to find the slope between these two points. Using the slope formula, we know that this slope is:
\begin{align*}
m &= \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x - x_0} \\
m(x - x_0) &= f(x) - f(x_0) \\
f(x_0) + m(x - x_0) &= f(x) \\
f(x) &= f(x_0) + m(x - x_0)
\end{align*}

Now provided that $x$ and $x_0$ are "close enough", we can approximate the slope of the tangent line of $f$ at $x_0$ to be $m$. Hence, we obtain:
$$
f(x) \approx f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x - x_0)
$$

Comment: This makes a lot of sense!  Thank you!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! =]

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to Sanath Devalapurkar's answer, this is not really an instance of Taylor series so much as Taylor series are a generalization of this.  There are two parts to linear approximation: the formula for the line, and the fact that it is an approximation to the function.

- The formula for the line is, as you say, just the point-slope formula for the line with slope $f'(x_0)$ passing through the point $(x_0, f(x_0))$; i.e. it is a line through a point of the graph of $f$ whose slope is the derivative of $f$ there.
- The fact that this is actually an approximation to $f$ is the definition of the derivative.  To see this, let $L(x) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0) (x - x_0)$ be the function for the tangent line.  Then the definition of $f'(x_0)$ is
  $$\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x) - L(x)}{x - x_0} = \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x - x_0} - f'(x_0) = 0,$$
  which says, intuitively, that when $x$ is close enough to $x_0$ that their difference $x - x_0$ is tiny, the difference $f(x) - L(x)$ is tiny even when compared to that.  This is the sense in which $L(x)$ is a good approximation to $f(x)$.

For Newton's method, see [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), which has a nice animation.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying things!  :)

Answer (score 1):

The [Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) (see the link for a "technical" introduction) of $f(x)$ about $x_0$ approximates the value of $f(x)$ in some sufficiently small neighborhood of $x_0$:
$$f(x)= \sum_{n=0} ^ {\infty} \frac {f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!} \, (x-x_0)^{n}$$
Your above written formula is the first-order approximation. To see **why** Taylor series work, visit [this page](http://www.ugrad.math.ubc.ca/coursedoc/math101/notes/series/powers.html). Also, see [this M.SE question](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEwQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmath.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F182831%2Fhow-do-taylor-polynomials-work-to-approximate-functions&ei=YAZUU_WFGZCZyATmgoG4Ag&usg=AFQjCNH5TPIHn2cNA0GY8hGgs4BX7s2Gxg&bvm=bv.65058239,d.aWw).

Comment: So that is the Taylor Series of $f'(x_0)$?

Comment: @Ethan No - $f(x)\approx f(x_0)+f^\prime(x_0)(x-x_0)$ is the first order approximation of $f(x)$ **about** $x_0$. To see this intuitionistically, draw a circle about any point $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Ah, okay.  I understand this now.  Thank you!